# Open file in Sublime Text tab via AppleScript

Tags: applescript, sublimetext

Using the following AppleScript code, I can open a .txt file in a new window of Sublime Text:

```
tell application "Sublime Text"
    open "Users:me:Desktop:foo.txt"
end tell
```

Is there a way to open this file NOT as its own new window, but rather as a new tab of my existing window of Sublime Text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sublime Text doesn't provide an AppleScript suite, but does provide a command line utility ‘subl’ in:

```
/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl
```

Usage is available with `--help`.

subl is aware of the current window when opening files and adds the file as a tab.

```
/Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl /path/to/file
```

To run this in AppleScript, use ‘do shell script’.

```
do shell script ¬
    "/Applications/Sublime\\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl /path/to/file"
```

```
do shell script 
    "/Applications/Sublime\\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl " ¬
    & quoted form of POSIX path of (alias "path:to:file")
```

Comment: You're a wizard!  The only tweak I had to make was to put two backslashes to escape the space in your AppleScript example, but it worked like a charm!

Comment: You might need to use `quoted form of POSIX path of...`, which will escape the path string before sending it to `do shell script` ( e.g. if `/path/to/file` contains any spaces, etc.).